# Registering command line arguments with help system: Boost-Build

Tags: bjam, boost-build

We're using [Boost-Build](https://github.com/boostorg/build) to build our software. To help facilitate this, we've written a library of rules and actions. Boost-Build allows passing in command line arguments and will pass along any argument prefixed with `--`. Currently, to get a hold of the arguments and check for flags we're doing something like:

```
import modules ;

local args = [ modules.peek : ARGV ] ;
# or like this
if "--my-flag" in [ modules.peek : ARGV ]
```

Which works to get and check values. However, developers that use Boost-Build and our jam libraries have no idea that these flags are available and would like to see some help on these flags whenever they run either `bjam -h` or `bjam --help`. I see that BB has a [help](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/options/help.jam) module, but I don't see any way to register arguments with the help system.

Is there a way to register command line flags, complete with short documentation, that the help system will pick up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to my own question, I have added the very feature that I was asking about: https://github.com/boostorg/build/pull/23

It uses the existing options plugin system. Whenever you want to create a new command-line option create a new module within the `options` directory. Within that new module, create a variable that holds a value or is empty. Above the variable create a comment. The comment is used as the command-line documentation and the value (if given) is used to describe the default value of that variable.

Create a `process` rule within the new module and register your option with the system. This allows importing the `option` module and getting the value from a single source. This requires that each variable name is prefixed with the name of the module.

Create a variable named `.option-description`. Its value is the section separator and its comment is the description of the section.

For example:

```
# within options/cool.jam

# These are the options for the Cool option plugin
.option-description = Cool Options

# This enables option1
.option.--cool-option1 ?= ;

# This enables something cool
.option.--cool-default-option ?= "my default value" ;

rule process (
    command # The option.
    : values * # The values, starting after the "=".
    )
{
    option.set $(command) : $(values) ;
}
```

When running `bjam` with the `--help-options` flag, it will output all modules that follow the above patterns within the `options` directory. It will have an output similar to the following:

```
Boost.Build Usage:

  b2 [ options... ] targets...

  * -a; Build all targets, even if they are current.
  * -fx; Read 'x' as the Jamfile for building instead of searching for the
    Boost.Build system.
  * -jx; Run up to 'x' commands concurrently.
  * -n; Do not execute build commands. Instead print out the commands as they
    would be executed if building.
  * -ox; Output the used build commands to file 'x'.
  * -q; Quit as soon as a build failure is encountered. Without this option
    Boost.Jam will continue building as many targets as it can.
  * -sx=y; Sets a Jam variable 'x' to the value 'y', overriding any value that
    variable would have from the environment.
  * -tx; Rebuild the target 'x', even if it is up-to-date.
  * -v; Display the version of b2.
  * --x; Any option not explicitly handled by Boost.Build remains available to
    build scripts using the 'ARGV' variable.
  * --abbreviate-paths; Use abbreviated paths for targets.
  * --hash; Shorten target paths by using an MD5 hash.
  * -dn; Enables output of diagnostic messages. The debug level 'n' and all
    below it are enabled by this option.
  * -d+n; Enables output of diagnostic messages. Only the output for debug
    level 'n' is enabled.

Debug Levels:

  Each debug level shows a different set of information. Usually with higher
  levels producing more verbose information. The following levels are supported:

  * 0; Turn off all diagnostic output. Only errors are reported.
  * 1; Show the actions taken for building targets, as they are executed.
  * 2; Show quiet actions and display all action text, as they are executed.
  * 3; Show dependency analysis, and target/source timestamps/paths.
  * 4; Show arguments of shell invocations.
  * 5; Show rule invocations and variable expansions.
  * 6; Show directory/header file/archive scans, and attempts at binding to
    targets.
  * 7; Show variable settings.
  * 8; Show variable fetches, variable expansions, and evaluation of 'if'
    expressions.
  * 9; Show variable manipulation, scanner tokens, and memory usage.
  * 10; Show execution times for rules.
  * 11; Show parsing progress of Jamfiles.
  * 12; Show graph for target dependencies.
  * 13; Show changes in target status (fate).

Cool Options:
    These are the options for the Cool option plugin

    * --cool-option1: This enables option1. Default is disabled.
    * --cool-default-option: This enables something cool. "my default value".
```

Later on in your own Jam code, you can then get a hold of values from the registered options by doing:

```
import option ;

option1 = option.get '--cool-option1' ;
if $(option1) {
    # do_something ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "register" individual options with the B2 help system. As generally that's just not how the help system works. The help system documents B2 modules (i.e. classes) and projects (i.e. jamfiles) only. What you see when you do "b2 --help" is a collection of the project help information and module information. All the data is extracted from the parse jamfiles.

For modules you add comments to classes and arguments and they get formatted for output. For example take a look at the "[container.jam](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/util/container.jam)" source. In that the second comment on the file is a module help doc, the comment before "class node" is a class help doc, the comment before "rule set" is a method help doc, and the comment after the "value ?" argument is a help doc.

For projects the second comment in the project's jamfile is taken as the help doc. For example the Boost [Jamroot](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/blob/master/Jamroot) has a large help doc comment for the usage information. This is printed out if you:

```
cd <boost-root>
b2 --help
```

If you such a comment to one of your project jamfiles (note: it assumes the first comment is a copyright notice and hence skips it and uses the second comment block for the help doc), and cd to that project directory and do `b2 --help` you should see it printed.

Which type of help doc you want is of course dependent on your project and your intentions.